# Conjecture: There are infinitely many $N$ such that $0\equiv N\pmod2$, $1\equiv N\pmod3$, and $0\leq N\pmod P\leq P-4$ for primes $P$ with $5\leq P<N$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, prime-gaps

**Here's a conjecture,**

There are infinitely many numbers $N$, such that for all prime numbers $P<N$

$0 \equiv N \pmod 2$ and
$1 \equiv N \pmod 3$ and
$0 \leq N \pmod P \leq (P-4)$, for $P \geq 5$

---

For eg: 10

$10$ mod $2$ $\equiv 0$
$10$ mod $3$ $\equiv 1$
$10$ mod $5$ $\equiv 0$
$10$ mod $7$ $\equiv 3$

---

Is this a known conjecture? Does it have a proof?

If not, is there a way to prove or disprove this?

Comment: Computer scientists use $N\% p$ to denote the remainder and, like I say, I think it's clear what you intended.  In algebra, I think it's more common to use $N\pmod p$ to denote the whole equivalence class, and not just the least positive member of it.

Comment: Should say:  I don't have time to think about your question now.   First thing I'd do is to search.  How many "good" $N$ are there less than $1000$, say?

Comment: @lulu maybe there are like 15 of them

Comment: Looks good.  I'll delete my earlier comments.

Comment: @AaronHendrickson thanks

Comment: It is incorrect to say "There are infinite numbers" when you mean "There are infinitely many numbers".  If $N_1$ is (in some sense) an "infinite number" and so is $N_2,$ then $N_1,N_2$ are infinite numbers, but NOT infinitely many numbers.

Comment: @lulu the possible N are probably a subset of $2^m$$3^n$ $-2$. where m and n are positive integers

Comment: @MichaelHardy yes, this makes it more clear, thank you

Comment: Mr Green - subset of 2^m 3^n - 2: I don’t see that.

Comment: @gnasher729 because it must be even (both parts have to be same parity), and it has to be 2 less than a multiple of 3.

Answer (score 1):

The first two conditions force N = 4 (modulo 6) and N+2 is a multiple of 6.

If N + 2 = 6pq where p >= 5 is a prime, then N+2 is divisible by p, therefore N = (p-2) modulo p, so N doesn’t meet the conditions. Therefore the only choices for N are $N = 2^m 3^n - 2$ where n, m >= 1.

There are 1178 such numbers $N < 2^{64}-2$. 62 don’t fail for any prime < 1,000. 32 don’t fail for any prime < 100,000 and 27 don’t fail for any prime p.

The largest N is $N = 2^{32} 3^{15} - 2<2^{56}$. Numerical results are inconclusive either way.

For the curious:

```
2^ 1 * 3^ 1 - 2 =                      4
2^ 2 * 3^ 1 - 2 =                     10
2^ 1 * 3^ 2 - 2 =                     16
2^ 3 * 3^ 2 - 2 =                     70
2^ 2 * 3^ 3 - 2 =                    106
2^ 6 * 3^ 1 - 2 =                    190
2^ 4 * 3^ 3 - 2 =                    430
2^ 7 * 3^ 2 - 2 =                  1,150
2^ 5 * 3^ 4 - 2 =                  2,590
2^ 6 * 3^ 7 - 2 =                139,966
2^ 3 * 3^10 - 2 =                472,390
2^18 * 3^ 1 - 2 =                786,430
2^12 * 3^ 5 - 2 =                995,326
2^ 2 * 3^15 - 2 =             57,395,626
2^18 * 3^ 5 - 2 =             63,700,990
2^21 * 3^ 4 - 2 =            169,869,310
2^24 * 3^ 5 - 2 =          4,076,863,486
2^27 * 3^ 4 - 2 =         10,871,635,966
2^30 * 3^ 7 - 2 =      2,348,273,369,086
2^33 * 3^ 8 - 2 =     56,358,560,858,110
2^43 * 3^ 2 - 2 =     79,164,837,199,870
2^32 * 3^ 9 - 2 =     84,537,841,287,166
2^36 * 3^ 7 - 2 =    150,289,495,621,630
2^11 * 3^24 - 2 =    578,415,690,713,086
2^31 * 3^12 - 2 =  1,141,260,857,376,766
2^43 * 3^ 8 - 2 = 57,711,166,318,706,686
2^32 * 3^15 - 2 = 61,628,086,298,345,470
```

Comment: How did you calculate all these??

Comment: So there seems to be atleast, in this analysis infinitely many such numbers..?? Is this conjecture known. Can this be proved??

Comment: Could you list these 27 results, with factorization of $N+2$?

Comment: 1. Proved there are definitely no other numbers. 2. Made a sieve of primes up to 10 billion. 3. Easy to generate all the possible N ip to 2^64. Check for each prime p whether N modulo p is greater than p-4; almost half drop out for p=5 or p=7 already.

Comment: Me Green Gould, it’s hard to say if there are infinitely many. Among larger numbers it’s more rare that one passes the test, since there are more primes. This might go either way.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the question slightly to an equivalent question: Are there infinitely many N = 4 modulo 6, so that N+1, N+2 and N+3 are not divisibly by any prime 5 <= p < N?

N+2 must be of the form $2^n 3^m$: If N+2 = 6k is not of this form, then k has a prime factor p < N. So we restrict N to the form $N = 2^n 3^m - 2$, and since N+2 has no prime factor ≥ 5, the question is: Does N+1 or N+3 have such a prime factor?

N+1 = 5 modulo 6, and N+3 = 7 modulo 6. N+1 and N+3 are both greater than N, so the question is: Is either N+1 or N+3 composite? So solutions are $N = 2^n 3^m - 2$ where N+1 and N+3 are twin primes.

For random x, the chance that (x, x+2) are twin primes is about $0.66 / log^2 x$. But with x = 5 (modulo 6), neither is divisible by 2 or 3, where for the other cases at least one is divisible by 2 or 3, so the chances are 6 times hight, about $4 / log^2 x$. There are about $n / log_2(3)$ candidates $2^{n-1} < N < 2^n$, each is a solution with probability $4 / n^2$, so I expect about $4 / log_2(3) / n$ solutions between $2^{n-1} < N < 2^n$. That's the harmonic series, so about $4 log n / log_2(3)$ solutions N < 2^n. This would be a very, very slowly growing function.

So this heuristic seems to show a very, very slowly growing function going towards infinity. But since its growing so slowly, any heuristics that reduces the number just a tiny bit may be enough to make this false.

To find examples for N: Generate numbers $N = 2^n 3^m - 2$, n, m ≥ 1, then check whether N+1 or N+2 have small prime factors, and if need perform a non-deterministic primality test for N+1 and N+3.

Comment: Excellent work, but just because the probability goes down we can't conclude that it doesn't go on to infinitely. Prime numbers alsovgo one becoming less amd less often but never stop

Comment: You have excellently unravalled the question. I reverse conjectured this from twin prime. This is a sub set of twin prime conjecture. If this conjecture is true, then twin prime conjecture is also true.